# Proof that $X_1 \backsim Pois(\lambda_1) $ and $X_2 \backsim Pois(\lambda_2) $ then $X_1 + X_2 \backsim Pois(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) $

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to prove that if two random variables (independent) $X_1 \backsim  Pois(\lambda_1)  $ and $X_2 \backsim  Pois(\lambda_2)  $ then $X_1 + X_2 \backsim  Pois(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)   $.

$$P(X_1+X_2 = k) =  \sum_{k_1 =0}^{k}P(X_1 = k_1) P(X_2 = k- k_1) = e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)}\sum_{k_1 =0}^{k} \frac{\lambda_1 ^{k_1} \lambda_2
 ^{k-k_1}}{k_1!(k-k_1)!} =...  $$
but I stucked in given sum. It seems that
$$\sum_{k_1 =0}^{k} \frac{\lambda_1 ^{k_1} \lambda_2
 ^{k-k_1}}{k_1!(k-k_1)!} = \frac{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)^k}{k!},$$
but I don't see how to prove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the binomial theorem $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}.$$  You should observe $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

Answer (score 3):

An other approach is to calculate the characteristic function of $X_1 + X_2$.
The characteristic function of a Poisson distributed variable with parameter $\lambda$ is given by $\phi_\lambda(t) = \exp(-\lambda(1-e^{it}))$.
Then we have that
$$\phi_{X_1 + X_2}(t) = \phi_{X_1}(t) \phi_{X_2}(t) = \exp(-\lambda_1(1-e^{it})) \exp(-\lambda_2(1-e^{it})) = \exp(-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(1-e^{it})),$$
which is the characteristic function of a Poisson distributed variable with parameter $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. Because the characteristic function uniquely characterises the distribution of a r.v., it follows that $X_1 + X_2 \sim Pois(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$.